# character formula for demazure modules

Tags: lie-algebras

Is there any character formula for demazure modules in arbitary kac moody settings which does not use demazure operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryom-Hansen, Steen(DK-CPNH)
Littelmann's refined Demazure character formula revisited. (English summary) 
Sém. Lothar. Combin. 49 (2002/04), Art. B49d, 10 pp.

The review:

"The author provides a purely combinatorial proof the Demazure character formula, a generalisation of Weyl's character formula. This is done using only the combinatorial properties of crystals, namely Kashiwara's crystal operators and the ∗-operation. Prior proofs required an appeal to either representation theory or Littelmann's path models."

Comment: Here is an accessible link to the article, which is short but includes comments and references for the tangled history of the original Demazure formula and its generalizations:
http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~slc/

However, I'm not sure about the interaction of the Kac-Moody setting with the quantum group setting used in Ryom-Hansen's approach.   

Answer (score 1):

Littelmann's, which gives a positive formula (counting Littelmann paths). His ICM address is here: http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1994.1/Main/icm1994.1.0298.0308.ocr.pdf

He proves its *validity* using Demazure operators -- I hope that doesn't disqualify it!